# Find specific character after current cursor position

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find ';' character where location is after the current cursor position in multine textbox. Not All ';' just after the current cursor position.

Currently what i do is like below. Checking every lines for ';' character im loop and if it founds exit from loop. What should i write to 'if' command and if there is easier way to do this, please share with me ;

```
//uteSQL is my multiline textbox

string[] lines = this.uteSQL.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int countLines = lines.Length;

int cursorPos = uteSQL.SelectionStart;

  for(int t = uteSQL.SelectionStart; t <= countLines ; t++)
  {
     if ( find ';' character that i want every lines)
      {
          -- if it finds get the line number
          break;
      }
   }
```

Comment: What is this? Webforms? Winforms? MVC? Do you use `cursorPos` at all? What type is `uteSQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find ';' character where location is after the current cursor position in multine textbox.

You can use [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this.

```
var nextCharIndex = this.uteSQL.Text.IndexOf(";", uteSQL.SelectionStart);
```

If you want to find the line index of that found character you can do the following.

```
var nextCharIndex = this.uteSQL.Text.IndexOf(";", uteSQL.SelectionStart);
var lineIndexOfChar = nextCharIndex < 0 
    ? -1 
    : this.uteSQL.Text.Substring(0, nextCharIndex)
        .Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
```

Comment: that does not give line number

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I've added the part to count the lines

Answer (score 0):

```
int line = uteSQL.Text.Take(uteSQL.SelectionStart).Count('\n'.Equals) + 1;

int index = uteSQL.Text.IndexOf(';', uteSQL.SelectionStart);

int column = index - uteSQL.Text.LastIndexOf('\n', index);
```